# How do I pass a Model from a View, to another view, without data getting Lost?

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-viewmodel

I know the question might be strange, but i'm trying to pass data, that is filled in a View and returned to my Controller, to another View, to fill all variables. My Problem is, that every time when I pass the data, that is correctly received from the first View, to the second View, the second View returns me a new Model, with only the data, that is filled in the second View. For better understanding here my code:

Controller:

```
    [HttpPost]
public IActionResult SubmitCharInfo(Character character) {
    //charRepo.SaveCharacter(character);
    return View("Char_StandartAttributes", character);
}

[HttpPost]
public IActionResult CharAllSkills(Character character) {
    charRepo.UpdateCharacter(character);
    return View("Char_FirstSkillPage");
}
```

The Code from my first View:

```
    @model Character

<form method="post" asp-action="SubmitCharInfo">
    <input type="hidden" asp-for="ownerID" />
    <input type="hidden" asp-for="charID" />
    <table  class="table table-bordered table-dark text-center">
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <th>Enter a character name:</th>
                <td><input asp-for="charName" class="input-validation-error" data-for="true" data-val-required="Please enter your phone number" /></td>

            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th>Enter a age:</th>
                <td><input asp-for="charAge"/></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th>Enter a job:</th>
                <td><input asp-for="charJob" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th>Enter a place of residence:</th>
                <td><input asp-for="charPOR" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th>Enter a gender:</th>
                <td><input asp-for="charGender" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th>
                    <div data-valmsg-for="charStory" data-valmsg-replace="true" class="alert-danger"></div>
                    Enter a story:
                </th>
                <td><input asp-for="charStory" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="2">
                    <button type="submit" class="btn">Submit</button>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</form>
```

And here the Code of my second View:

```
@model Character


<form method="post" asp-action="CharAllSkills">
    <table class="table table-bordered table-dark text-center">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th colspan="2"><h1>Standart Skills</h1></th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th colspan="2"><h3>Enter a value for...</h3></th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <th>close range combat:</th>
                <td><input asp-for="standartSkills.AttackeNahkampf" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th>stamina:</th>
                <td><input asp-for="standartSkills.Ausdauer" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th>inteligence:</th>
                <td><input asp-for="standartSkills.Intelligenz" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th>strength: </th>
                <td><input asp-for="standartSkills.Koerperkraft" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th>strength:</th>
                <td><input asp-for="standartSkills.MentaleBelastbarkeit" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th>weapon handling:</th>
                <td><input asp-for="standartSkills.Waffenumgang" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="2">
                    <button type="submit" class="btn">Submit</button>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</form>
```

Here is a live example of values:

[Values received from the first view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fma6S.png)

After passing the Model to the second view and receiving my model data changed to:

[Values from the second view#1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GJR9C.png)

[Values from the second view#2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5suAv.png)

Why does this happen and how to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After return view, it is a new page. Passing parameters to the view is one way to retain data or reloading data from the database is another way.

New page: Data -> Model -> View -> Action -> gone!

Another new page: Data -> Model -> View -> Action -> gone!

So, you have to reload from the beginning after action.

Comment: So i have to save the data in a database?

Comment: Yes, search for asp.net mvc database setting, database context, and dbset. But you can test data without the help of database. Create model class (normal C# class), then create object in controller, and pass it to the view. Then, use action pass to another view or action.

Answer (score 1):

I am unsure if your question makes sense, but that might jsut be my lack of udnerstanding regarding the MVC.

The [page lifecycle](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472.aspx) dictates that a page is to be build, the postback be processed, the whole thing to be send to the user and dropped from memory ASAP. A page (View+Model) will not even be in memory after it has been send to the user. Data can not persist in Model or View.

If you need to keep data between postbacks, you have to save it someplace outside the page. Databases are very common. ASP.Net also has some less persistent session-related storage approaches. And once you have the data persistet retrieving it for Model A or Model B is a trivial detail.

Comment: Thanks for this quick reply, i think you understood me pretty well. I will try to save and update the received data from each View to a database.